# Youtube video full screen is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, youtube

Youtube video full screen is not working in firefox(ver 28).

here is my code

```
<div class="video-div-container">
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/eMalsA4LiSQ?rel=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&wmode=transparent"
                    width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

When i click the full screen button, the iframe will become black.

The above code is working fine in google chrome. If i remove &wmode=transparent from the url, it will work fine firefox also. I cannot remove the &wmode=transparent as i have z-index issue

Please help me to  solve this issue.

Comment: What is the z-index issue if you remove &wmode=transparent from the url?

Comment: bootstrap modals and alerts are coming under the iframe. i added &wmode=transparent to solve that issue

Comment: Okay, what happens if you change to `&wmode=opaque`?

Comment: Just tested this fiddle in FF28 and I'm not getting any issues: http://jsfiddle.net/WM3Ly/

Comment: thanks for the updates. the same jsfiddle is not working in my firefox(ubuntu os). any idea?

Comment: As it's working on my browser I have a feeling it may be specific to your machine. See here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/flash-video-wont-play-full-screen

Comment: thanks dude. let me try that

Comment: No worries mate, let me know if it works and I can stick it on as an answer

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this?

```
<div class="video-div-container">
<div class="video-container">
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/eMalsA4LiSQ?rel=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&wmode=transparent&fs=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

&fs=1 for triggering fullscreen button and **webkitallowfullscreen, mozallowfullscreen** for solving browser specific issues.

Comment: sorry. there is no difference